# Schwartz space on $\bigcup_{n=1}^CR^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, special-functions

I have an application where I need to work with the following idea.
Let the space $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb{R}^n$ be associated with the metric $d$ such that for $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$, we have 
$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^n\vert{x_i-y_i}\vert &\text{if } n=m, \\
\vert{m-n}\vert & \text{Otherwise. }  \end{cases}$

A function $\phi$ on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb{R}^n$ is a collection of functions $\{\phi_n, 1\leq n\leq C\}$, where $\phi_n$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.Similarly, let $\nu$ be a finite measure defined on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb{R}^n$.

I need to work with the Schwartz space on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb R^n$ and its dual by defining an inner product as
$\langle\nu,\phi\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^C\int_{\mathbb R^n}\phi(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\ d\nu(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$. Do all the properties of Schwartz space and its dual on just $\mathbb R^n$ holds even for the case of the space $\bigcup_{n=1}^C\mathbb R^n$? If it is true, can we extend this to the case when $C=\infty$? Please give some suggestions and references for this.

I work on the stochastic interacting particle systems containing $N$ particles in which each particle state lies in the space $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb R^n$. The counting measure $\nu$ on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb R^n$ can be considered as a collection of $C$ counting measures $\nu=(\nu_n,1\leq n\leq C)$ where $\nu_n$ for $1\leq n\leq C$ is a counting measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. By considering $\nu$ lies in the dual of a Schwartz space, I want to establish the functional central limit theorem  by taking $N\to\infty$ using the Mitoma's theorem. In general, the results are known for the case when $\nu$ lies on just $\mathbb{R}^n$. In my case, I can view $\nu$ as a single measure on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb R^n$ or a collection of measures $(\nu_n,1\leq n\leq C)$ where $\nu_n$ lies on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If I view $\nu$ as collection of measures, a sequence of measures $\{\eta^m\}$ converges to $\eta$ if $\{\eta^m_i\}$ converges to $\eta_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq C$. I am looking at the notion of the convergence of the measures on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C \mathbb R^n$ by considering they lie in the dual of a Schwartz space. Please let me know any useful references or suggestions.

Comment: Is that union disjoint? (otherwise, for finite $C$, I don't see any difference with $\mathbb{R}^C$)

Comment: You should explain what you mean by $\cup_{n=1}^C{\mathbb R}^n$.

Comment: In $\bigcup_{n=1}^C\mathbb{R}^n$, the union is disjoint. We us $l_1$ norm on the space $R^n$.

Comment: What about $\phi$ and $\nu$? How many arguments do they take? (Or should there by $\phi_n$, $n=1,\dots,C$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$?)

Comment: A function $\phi$ defined on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C\mathbb{R}^n$ is a collection of $\phi_n$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $1\leq n\leq C$. If $y$ is an element in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\phi(y)=\phi_n(y)$ and similarily, we define $\nu$ on $\bigcup_{n=1}^C\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Naive question trying to understand your post: if I write $\mathcal{S}_n$ for the Schwartz space on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is your "Schwartz space on $\cup_{n = 1}^C \mathbb{R}^n$" just $\oplus_{n = 1}^C \mathcal{S}_n$? Or is it something else?

Comment: (Also, as an aside: it is generally a good idea to edit any and all clarifications into the original post itself, so new readers won't have to dig through the comments for those bits of information.)

Comment: I would also like to see some clarification on the sentence "I need to work with the Schwartz space on $\bigcup_n \mathbb{R}^n$". Why exactly do you *need* to do that? Taking a setwise union of vector spaces is something so weird that I would like to know what drove you to it. I mean, even the types of the elements don't match. Why would anyone ever want to unionise these spaces? Are you sure you're not trying to do something completely different here?

Comment: I'd second @JohannesHahn's question about whether your really want a disjoint union of $\mathbb R^n$'s, or maybe something else. Ascending union of them, for example?

Comment: I think the OP really means disjoint union of the type $\cup_n X^n$. This is not uncommon especially with interacting particle system picture in the background. The linear structure of $X$ plays no role.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam How does the linear structure not play a role? How does one define the Schwartz space without it?

Comment: @JohannesHahn: I think the OP is talking about a Schwartz space of real or complex valued functions on $\cup_n X^n$ rather than trying to make $\cup_n X^n$ itself as some kind of linear space.

Comment: Again: What does that even mean? What is "Schwartz space on a set/metric space" supposed to mean?

Comment: @JohannesHahn: sets/metric spaces are too poor indeed for a Schwartz space to live on them, but you can take Nash manifolds: https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/doi/10.1093/imrn/rnm155/687431 That should already give a lot of interesting examples which have no linear structure.

Comment: What about the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the usual Schwartz space of smooth rapidly decaying functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$. As suggested in Willie Wong's comment it seems the wanted space is just $S=\oplus_{n=1}^{C}\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\prod_{n=1}^{C}\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the product topology. It turns out, as topological vector spaces, $S\simeq\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$. This follows from the Hermite representation, see, e.g., [this article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1665472) by Simon (there is a nicer presentation in his new comprehensive course on analysis).

Let $\langle x\rangle=\sqrt{1+\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i^2}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$
and in particular also for multiindices $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^{d}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$. For $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and for a (multi)sequence $z=(z_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^d}$
define
$$
||z||_{k}=\sup_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^d} \langle \alpha\rangle^k |z_{\alpha}|
\in [0,\infty]\ .
$$
Let 
$\mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0^{d})$ be the space of $z$'s such that $\forall k, ||z||_k<\infty$ with the topology defined by these seminorms. Then the Hermite representation says that $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)\simeq\mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0^{d})$ (the Hermite functions or eigenstates of the $d$-dimensional harmonic oscillator form an unconditional Schauder basis of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. By a (polynomially bounded) relabeling, $\mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0^{d})\simeq\mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0)$.
So
$$
S\simeq \prod_{n=1}^{C} \mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0)\simeq \mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0^{d})
$$
where the last isomorphism follows by interlacing.

The dual $S'$ is well-defined. My (wild) guess is that the OP is interested in a limit theorem of probability (like the CLT) on $S'$. This is about the weak convergence of Borel probability measures on $S'$ with the strong topology. By a theorem of Fernique this amounts to showing pointwise convergence of characteristic functions to a function on $S$ which is continuous at the origin. Tightness (I suppose that's why the OP refers to Mitoma's Theorem) is also equivalent to equicontinuity of characteristic functions at the origin.
A recent account of such topics is in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09326).

This also works for $C=\infty$ but one has at least two choices.
One option is to take the Borchers algebra
$$
S=\oplus_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
with the topology defined by all seminorms which are continuous on individual summands. Then $S'$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$
the space of (not necessarily temperate) distributions.

Another is to take for $S$ a space of sequences of sequences $z^{(m)}$ with fast decay in the $m$ direction too. But this is the same as $\mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}_0^2)$.

Comment: Thank for your time and providing a detailed answer.